# Task Page Recurrence functionality on a VF page

Tags: visualforce, tasks

Has anyone replicated the task recurrence functionality on a VF page? can give me some help thanks in advance.

Comment: @LaceySnr i don't find answer there

Comment: Sure, but having a separate question for the same thing doesn't help. SFSE aims to avoid duplicate questions so that there's a better chance of finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, I hope this works

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000099MtIAI

Comment: not work same question there but no answer is provided